# Xamarin listview outlining issues

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, alignment, multiple-columns

I am trying to make a listview in Xamarin with 3 columns, having 1 imageview and 2 textviews. The imageview should be aligned to the left (working), the first textview should be in the middle, all aligned under each other, so that all first letters align. and the 3rd column should be all the way on the right and this is not working, the value of the 3rd column is directly set behind the text of the 2nd column.

> The text should be centered verticaly in the row, but this is also not
>   working although the android:gravity="center_vertical" is set.

My code :

[image: axml code]

Listview with everything wrong displayed as shown :

[image: listview with everything wrong displayed]

Comment: A helpful strategy here is to color the backgrounds of the views so that you can see their boundries (including the containing view's background). Then you can start experimenting with the layout position attributes to better see their effects and begin to ascertain their behavior.

Comment: Nice tip, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_item_menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/layout_item_menu_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout_item_menu_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/layout_item_menu_image"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="TEXT 2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout_item_menu_text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_item_menu_image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/layout_item_menu_text2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEXT 1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is problems with posting your code sample, I'll post this layout that may be adapted to your situation

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rl_outer"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dip">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_inner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">      

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center"/>     

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_text2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_text1"
      android:gravity="right"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```